# Trying to get an API / URL to show in my UILabel text?

Tags: swift, url

I am try to get my UILabel text to equal the url text I am not getting any errors but it just is not doing anything not sure what I am doing wrong?

```
let tasks = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("error")
        } else {
            if let content = data {
                do {
                    let Json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject
                    if let data = Json as? NSString {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.myLabel.text = "\(data)"
                        }

                    }

                } catch {


                }
            }

        }

    }
    tasks.resume()
```

Comment: What you mean by `equal the url text `  , are this API Service or what , Are api response is just string not Json format , you have to give more information about your URL and your need

Comment: this is right before the other code. let url = URL(string: "https://talaikis.com/api/quotes/random/")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your API Response is not `String` , It's `Dictionary`  Dictionary in json  is `{}`

**API Response:**

```
{
    quote: "Travel is the most private of pleasures. There is no greater bore than the travel bore. We do not in the least want to hear what he has seen in Hong Kong.",
    author: "Vita Sackville-West",
   cat: "travel"
}
```

so you will not pass this condition at this line   `if let data = Json as? NSString`   because data is `Dictionary` not `String`

**Correct solution :**

```
   let tasks = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: "https://talaikis.com/api/quotes/random/")!) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("error")
            } else {
                if let content = data {
                    do {
                        let Json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject
                        if let data = Json as? [AnyHashable:Any] {

                            if let quote = data["quote"] as? String {
                                print(quote)
                            }

                            if let author = data["author"] as? String {
                                print(author)
                            }

                            if let cat = data["cat"] as? String {
                                print(cat)
                            }
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                              self.myLabel.text = "\(quote)"
                            }

                        }

                    } catch {


                    }
                }

            }

        }
        tasks.resume()


    }
```